# How to find the maximum date value with conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a three columns dataframe as follows. I want to calculate the returns in three months per day for every funds, so I need to get the date with recorded NAV data three months ago. Should I use the max() function with filter() function to deal this problem? If so, how? If not, could you please help me figure out a better way to do this?

| fund code | date | NAV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-04 | 1.0000 |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-05 | 1.0001 |
| fund 1 | 2021-01-06 | 1.0023 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-08 | 1.0000 |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-09 | 0.9998 |
| fund 2 | 2020-02-10 | 1.0001 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-04 | 2.0021 |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-05 | 2.0044 |
| fund 3 | 2022-05-06 | 2.0305 |

I tried to combined the max() function with filter() as follows:

`max(filter(lambda x: x<=df['date']-timedelta(days=91)))`
But it didn't work.

Were this in excel, I know I could use the following functions to solve this problem:
`{max(if(B:B<=B2-91,B:B))}`

`{max(if(B:B<=B3-91,B:B))}`

`{max(if(B:B<=B4-91,B:B))}`

`....`

But with python, I don't know what I could do. I just learnt it three days ago. Please help me.

This picture is what I want if it was in excel. The yellow area is the original data. The white part is the procedure I need for the calculation and the red part is the result I want. To get this result, I need to divide the 3rd column by the 5th column.

[image: This picture is what I want if it was in excel. The yellow area is the original data. The white part is the procedure I need for the calculation and the red part is the result I want. To get this result, I need to divide the 3rd column by the 5th column.]

I know that I could use pct_change(period=7) function to get the same results in this picture. But here is the tricky part: the line 7 rows before  is not necessarily the data 7 days before, and not all the funds are recorded daily. Some funds are recorded weekly, some monthly. So I need to check if the data used for division exists first.

Comment: What is the expected output that you need? Could you give an example from the table?

Comment: Thank you for your asking. I have just updated an example to show you the picture I have in my mind:)

Comment: If the data used for the division does not exist, i.e. the last recorded date was a month ago, how would you like to handle the percentage change? Do you want to return NaN? Or do you want to use the last available date for the calculation? Knowing this would help me to provide more informed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is an implementation of the maximum in sliding window (for your example 1 week, 7days).

I could recreated you example as follow (to create the data frame you have):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from random import randint
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["fund code", "date", "NAV"])
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-01-04", '%Y-%m-%d')
for i in range(10):
    df = df.append({"fund code": 'fund 1', "date": date + datetime.timedelta(i), "NAV":randint(0,10)}, ignore_index=True)
    
for i in range(20, 25):
    df = df.append({"fund code": 'fund 1', "date": date + datetime.timedelta(i), "NAV":randint(0,10)}, ignore_index=True)
    
for i in range(20, 25):
    df = df.append({"fund code": 'fund 2', "date": date + datetime.timedelta(i), "NAV":randint(0,10)}, ignore_index=True)
```

this will look like your example, with not continuous dates and two different funds.

The maximum sliding window (for variable days length look like this)

```
import queue
class max_queue:
    def __init__(self, win=7):
        self.win = win
        self.queue = queue.deque()
        self.date = None
    def append(self, date, value):
        
        while self.queue and value > self.queue[-1][1]:
            self.queue.pop()
            
        while self.queue and date - self.queue[0][0] >= datetime.timedelta(self.win):
            self.queue.popleft()
            
        self.queue.append((date, value))
        self.date = date
        
    def get_max(self):
        return self.queue[0][1]
```

now you could simply iterate over rows and get the max value in the timeframe you are interested.

```
mq = max_queue(7)
pre_code = ''
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    code, date, nav,*_ = row
    if code != pre_code:
        mq = max_queue(7)
    pre_code = code
    mq.append(date, nav)
    df.at[idx, 'max'] = mq.get_max()
```

results will look like this, with added max column. This assumes that funds data are continuous, but you could as well modify to have seperate max_queue for each funds as well.

[image]

using max queue to only keep track of the max in the window would be the correct complexity O(n) for a solution. important if you are dealing with huge datasets and especially bigger date ranges (instead of week).

Comment: Many thanks for your kind and detailed reviews. It helps a lot!